# Indices with nested property in both Kibana vizualization and index queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

So I have following problem which I'm trying to solve last two days. I have python script which parses logs and inserts data in elastic search, dynamically creating indices via bulk function.

Problem is my mapping has one `"type": "nested"` property, something like "users" field. And particularly when I'm only adding `"type": "nested"` in this property I can't query objects from Kibana nor creating any vizualization (because nested objects are separate documents If I'm not making mistakes). First think I tried: adding aditional `"include_in_parent": true` parameter to `users` field, but as result I got "wrong" queries (i.e. running something like `+users.name: 'test' +users.age: 30`) would result in ANY document which has those two fields, not exactly referring to ONE user object. Also vizualization was obviously wrong too.

Second solution I found was adding parent-child relationship. But this could be potentially be waste of time as I don't know will it result in correct queries. So I'm asking, if it will be normal solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Kibana doesn't support nested objects.
But ppadovani made this fork which supports this feature.

https://github.com/homeaway/kibana/tree/nestedSupport-4.5.4